# Adding a 'other, please specify' option to my ChoiceType form field in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create a form field with a set of choices with an extra text input which needs to be filled out if you choose 'other':

```
How often do you exercise?
(*) I do not exercise at the moment 
( ) Once a month
( ) Once a week
( ) Once a day
( ) Other, please specify: [             ]
```

Currently, I'm using a `ChoiceType` where I have set my `choices` like this:

```
$form->add('exercise', Type\ChoiceType::class, array(
    'label' => 'How often do you exercise?',
    'choices' => [ 'I do not excerise at the moment' => 'not', ... ],
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => [ new Assert\NotBlank() ],
));
```

How do I get the 'other, please specify' option to work as expected?

Comment: see similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519110/symfony-5-custom-choicetype-with-texttype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you will need to create custom form type which will be combination of `ChoiceType` and `TextType`. Nice intro to custom form types can be find id doc: http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/create_custom_field_type.html

This should be something similar to:

```
class ChoiceWithOtherType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // prepare passed $options

        $builder
            ->add('choice', Type\ChoiceType::class, $options)
            ->add('other', Type\TextType::class, $options)
        ;

        // this will requires also custom ModelTransformer
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer)

        // constraints can be added in listener
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            // ... adding the constraint if needed
        });

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // if needed
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // 
    }

));
```

Please take a look at:

- chapter about data transformers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html
- dynamic form modifications: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

I think the best way to achieve it is to take a look at the source code of the [DateTimeType](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to create a `ChoiceWithOtherType` (or something) class that extends `AbstractType` and then in my `buildForm()` method I need to create radio buttons for each choice. For the 'other, please specify' choice I need to create 2 inputs: a radio input and a text input. How would I make the text input required when the radio input is selected? I guess I need to add that constraint on POST?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you need more details.