# Symfony2.8 ChoiceType form filed with TextType form field

Tags: forms, symfony

In Symfony 2.8 when I edit or create a user, I create the UserType form to render all fields.

The UserType form has an Roles field which I get all roles and render it like checkbox.

The question is our boss want to add an input field at every each roles on the right.

The red color I marked section is the needed input section
[image: The red color I marked section is the needed input section].

In this way our boss can edit the input text box so that he can see more clearly every role's meaning.
How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move Roles to `DB` and store them as other entities. In such scenario you will need `Role` entity with at least two properties:

- `name`
- `description`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: At present, I do not intend to store to db. 
Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: If you want to load them for other users and have ability to update descriptions you need to store them somewhere.

Comment: I don't know how to store the special input field and how to render it along with the choice roles.

Comment: You will need similar solution to one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115490/adding-a-other-please-specify-option-to-my-choicetype-form-field-in-symfony/39115942#39115942

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try!

Comment: What good advice about store the special input field. Adding a new field in user entity?

Comment: No, I would recommend storing your roles in AclRole entity with properties like: `name`, `description`.

Comment: These display roles are dynamically acquired from the security role_hierarchy option. If store to database , It means 
compared with each other every time if want to edit ? 
It looks like quite appropriate.